# How to get multiple selected cell array values with checkbox in jquery, then send with ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How should I get an array value from a table cell when clicking checkbox with jQuery? If I've selected cell 1, I want to get array like `["BlackBerry Bold", "2/5", "UK"]`, but if I've selected all of them, I want to get all the data in the form of an array of arrays.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
  <th>Cell phone</th>
  <th>Rating</th>
  <th>Location</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
  <td>2/5</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
  <td>3.5/5</td>
  <td>US</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>Droid X</td>
  <td>4.5/5</td>
  <td>REB</td>
</tr>
```

Please help.

Comment: Next time ask a better question off the bat. I modified my answer 2 times for you before what you actually wanted was clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onclick get 3 children of the parent and add content to data. Used jquery nextAll for siblings and splice the 3 required.

- Attached event to the table, `onclick` will check if element is `INPUT`.
- If it's `input`, will get parent of that input which will be `<td>`.
- For this parent element, will get three siblings using jquery.
- Will add in selected if not present else delete, using indexOf.

CodePen for you to playaround: [ https://codepen.io/vivekamin/pen/oQMeXV ]

```js
   
let selectedData = []
let para = document.getElementById("selectedData");
let tableElem = document.getElementById("table");
tableElem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT' ){
    
    let parent = e.target.parentNode;
    let data  = [];
    $(parent).nextAll().map(function(index, node){
      data.push(node.textContent);
    })
 
    let index = selectedData.indexOf(JSON.stringify(data))
    if(index == -1){
       selectedData.push(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    else{
      selectedData.splice(index,1);
    }
   
    para.textContent = "";
    para.innerHTML = selectedData ;
  }
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="table">
<tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
  <th>Cell phone</th>
  <th>Rating</th>
  <th>Location</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
  <td>2/5</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
  <td>3.5/5</td>
  <td>US</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>Droid X</td>
  <td>4.5/5</td>
  <td>REB</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h3> Selected Data: </h3>
 <p id="selectedData"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to meet your needs.

1. create a function to build the array values based on looking for any checked inputs then going to their parents and grabbing the sibling text values
2. attach your change event to the checkbox click even.

I provided a fiddle below that will output the array in the console.

```
function buildTheArray(){
    var thearray = [];
    $("input:checked").parent().siblings().each(function(){
        thearray.push($(this).text());
    });
    return thearray;
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    console.log(buildTheArray());
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gcu4L5p6/

Comment: thanks, but if i select more than 1 cell the result will be like ["BlackBerry Bold 9650", "2/5", "UK"], ["Samsung Galaxy", "3.5/5", "US"]. how to get it?

Comment: Oh for that you'll need to move the logic that finds the values outside the event handler. I've updated the above!

Comment: I will say your table is basic and you'll have lots of issues if you do not take good care to use proper IDs or Class names. The structure is important. The code I provided is generic and will conflict if you have other similar structures.

Comment: results from above like ["BlackBerry Bold 9650", "2/5", "UK", "Samsung Galaxy", "3.5/5", "US"].
and how if i want to get result  like this? ["BlackBerry Bold 9650", "2/5", "UK"], ["Samsung Galaxy", "3.5/5", "US"].
thanks your so amazing